# Azure resource can't find dependancy when deploying

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Windows VM using templates and keep running into the error `code: InvalidResourceReference Resource X referenced by Resource Y was not found`. Resource X is `Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups` (named 'FBI') and resource Y is `Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces` (named vInterface).

All my required resources are created during this deployment with their dependencies set in the template. The first thing I did was confirm that my FBI resource exists, which it did:

[image]

Next I ensured that my FBI security group was listed as a dependency in vInterface to ensure that FBI does get created first before vInterface is created, which it is:

```
{
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        },
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "publicIpAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('VMGroup','Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[resourceId('VMGroup', 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            }
        }
    }
```

I can confirm that the location is the same for both of these resources. Everything *looks* ok but I can't figure out why my vInterface can't find/see my FBI security group.

For reference here's the full error message:

```
"error": {
"code": "InvalidResourceReference",
"message": "Resource /subscriptions/---/resourceGroups/VMGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/FBI referenced by resource /subscriptions/---/resourceGroups/VMDeployment/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/vInterface was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.",
"details": []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably deploying to a resource group not called `vmgroup` hence this error.

your resource id's are hardcoded to `vmgroup` resource group, not to the resource group you are deploying to; change your resourceId() input to:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
```

ps. you have it in 2 places.

Comment: Haha that'll teach me to do these things late in the day... Absolutely correct, thanks!